# Wordpress Display ONLY child and child

Tags: php, wordpress, list, categories

I want to display a category child and every child that is under that child.

My structure looks like this

- Page 1

  - Page 11
  - Page 12

    - Page 123
- Page 2

  - Page 22
  - Page 23

    - Page 234
- Page 3

Even if it have a Parent I dont want to display it, I only want to display Page 12 and one level down, and Page 23 and one level down. If Page 234 have a child it should not be displayed!

My Code, and it is inside the loop. And it displays every Category under Page 1, 2 and 3. That is what `wp_list_categories` do, but how can i solve this with maybe `wp_list_categories` or `get_category`?

```
<?php
if (is_category( )) {
  $cat = get_query_var('cat');
  $parent = get_category ($cat);
  if ($parent->parent) {
    wp_list_categories ('title_li=&child_of=' . $parent->parent);
  } else {
    wp_list_categories ('title_li=&child_of=' . $cat);
  }
}

?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `depth` parameter to decide the number of levels to be included in the list.

The structure I have:

- Cat 1 (ID: 238)

  - Cat 1.1 (ID: 239)
  - Cat 1.2 (ID: 240)

    - Cat 1.2.1 (ID: 241)

An example code from `category.php`:

```
$cat = get_query_var('cat');

$catObj = get_category($cat);
echo $catObj->name;

$args = array('hide_empty' => 0, 'child_of' => $cat, 'depth' => 1, 'title_li' => "");
wp_list_categories ($args);
```

Output of `/?cat=238`:

- Cat 1

  - Cat 1.1
  - Cat 1.2

Output of `/?cat=240`:

- Cat 1.2

  - Cat 1.2.1

You may ignore `hide_empty` and `title_li` parameters I have used. Take a look at the `wp_list_categories()` [reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) for additional parameters.